# providing root authentication for a qt program

Tags: linux, qt, authentication

I want to make a simple log capturing(of Linux system) gui application in QtCreator and as the log capturing data is a bit sensitive I want to add an authenticating window i.e. whenever I run my app, first a window asking for root authentication should pop up and then proceed.

Comment: so, what's exactly your question? how to authenticate a user as root?

Comment: Whenever we try to download any app from the ubuntu software centre we are greeted with an authentication window to enter the root password, i want to replicate the same for my program.

Comment: Is your problem implementing the new window to appear, or is your problem getting root privileges using given password?

Comment: yeah the problem is getting root privileges using given password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could simply use [`popen`](http://home.fhtw-berlin.de/~junghans/cref/FUNCTIONS/popen.html) for a `su root` command (which if I am not mistaken should not do anything by itself as it is executed in a seperate shell) and check the return message (`stdout`) as stated in the example from the link:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = popen( "ls -l", "r")
```

The return is probably system specific but it should be able to give you an idea whether the password is correct or not.

If you want a prompt to ask for root to even start the program, maybe [something like this](https://superuser.com/questions/435223/how-to-prompt-gui-and-use-root-password-on-a-script) is what you seek.